# Replay memory in Assassin's Creed Revelations

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-revelations

According to [Ubisoft's support document](http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15852/~/how-can-i-replay-missions%2Fmemories%3F), I can replay memories. However, I screwed up in Sequence 1 Memory 3 (A Journal of some kind) but it seems I cannot repeat it, the option is simply missing (this is true for all of the memories in sequence 1 so far; haven't completed the sequence yet so I don't know whether this issue is with later memories as well).

So are there memories that you are not supposed to repeat? Do I have to complete the sequence first? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the support document you linked:

> If you do not see the option to replay memory, this means you are already in a mission or at a point in the story where memory replays are not available

You're probably in this state in the game. If you're mid mission you can either finish it or can abandon it by pausing the game and choosing to exit memory in the menu. When you're outside a mission, the DNA option should be available in the menu.